# plt.show() not working in Sublime 2

Tags: python, matplotlib, sublimetext2

I am attempting to display graphs without saving them using matplotlib in Sublime. For some odd reason, plt.show() is not working. There are no compilation errors or any other hints that would be useful.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as r
randNum = r.randint(2,10)
randGraph = randStarGraph(randNum)
plt.show()
```

Anybody have any ideas?

**Edit:** I tried running Sait's code in Sublime. The graph failed to show. I ran the script from cmd, and the graph was successfully displayed on the screen, so it seems to be an issue with Sublime.

Comment: What is `randStarGraph` doing and where is it defined? Probably your issue is in that function as the rest looks pretty innocuous. Can't really say without seeing it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the fixes suggested above, I Upgraded to Sublime 3, which fixed my problem. I had not really considered upgrading before, however I am now quite impressed by the new features that version 3 has to offer.

http://www.sublimetext.com/3

Answer (score 0):

What is `randStarGraph()` doing and where is it defined?

Also, you don't call `nx.draw()` here, do you do it somewhere else?

You can test if sublime is working well with the following example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.complete_graph(5)
nx.draw(g)

plt.show()
```

Comment: randStarGraph() is a function that I created in order to a star shaped networkx graph.

Hm. It seems that your supplied code doesn't run either.